# Can a set of 3D positions be separated by plane?

Tags: mathematics, vector

I have 3 points in 3D space: A, B and C. I also have another set of 3D points: P, Q, R, S, T and U. What would be the simplest algorithm to figure out if there exists a plane that completely separates the first and second set? I know all the coordinates of all points.

Comment: This sounds like separating axis theorem, treating each cluster of points as a polygon. If there's a separating axis, then any plane normal to that axis between the two polygons is such a separating plane.

Comment: In fact, I think this is precisely equivalent to determining whether the convex hulls formed by each set of points intersect. So, you can use any convex hull collision detection method you prefer.

Comment: Do you need to know the plane if it exists? Or just If such plane exists?

Comment: Just if it exists.

Comment: Given the rather low number of combinations, I wouldnt be surprised if the most efficient way was just to test all of the 84 possible planes because the test itself is quite cheap when you already have a plane to test.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 21? A, B, C create one, and P, Q, R, S, T create 20 more combinations? 1 + 6! / 3!/ 3! = 21. Anyway, you might be right, that might be the quickest way of doing it. I will test that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can construct the convex hull of each point set, then test the convex hulls for intersection using your favourite convex collision detection algorithm (eg. SAT, GJK...)

If the two hulls intersect one another, or kiss at a point, then there is no plane that completely separates the two sets.

If there is a separation distance between them, then you have a choice of planes perpendicular to the separating axis, passing through any point in the gap in their projection onto the separating axis.

Answer (score 0):

You could find such a plane using a simple linear [support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). I wouldn't describe this as the "simplest" algorithm but there will definitely be a very fast solution using this method.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about refers to the linear separability of data (in your case in 3D). This is an explored topic in Machine Learning (which extends to N dimension). It was one of the reasons SVMs became extremely popular back in the day, as it computes the best hyper-plane (most distant related to two classes of categories), providing good performance for many problems. The topic known as [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) provides a rigorous analysis of this notion.

As mentioned in the comments the Convex Hull algorithm will compute this in 3D for you, as it will be the smallest polyhedron that will encapsulate a set of points. If these do not intersect you can have a plane between the two set of points.